# Team gathering for open source project

Tags: web-development

I'm a freelancer by myself and I'm looking for team that is willing to work on open source project for FREE. The problem is that I'm a freelancer and I know that there is no freelancer that is willing to spend their free time to work on open source project. I don't have enough money to pay anyone so I need a good website where I can gather this team.

Project  is website builder more like a Wordpress but with a lot of cool features. For example one of the features is logging file or a console. It will have themes, plugins, widgets, page creation tool, built in file management etc. Now you may ask why to create something that already exists? It's simple Wordpress is slow.

Now back to main question: is there any website where I can find developers and designers that are willing to work on this project for free?

Comment: Are you going to monetize/commercialize this endeavor at some point in the future? If so, will you be giving these freelancers an equity stake? If not, then you should not ask people to work on this for free.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to get people to invest their time in such a project is to build a *user base* that likes the project, finds it useful, and then contributes to it because they need added functionality (perhaps for their paid freelance project). I've been involved in many open source projects (mostly in the academic community) and the way to get people to contribute is to give them something useful they want to extend for their own projects.